# What was written on the wall beside the Doctor in "Heaven Sent"?

Tags: doctor-who

In Heaven Sent, 5:07 in, the doctor steps back from the window and there is writing on the wall.

[image]

Does anyone know what it says?

Comment: Just as a comment on the edit which happened while I was asleep. While I saw the writing on the wall, and presumably so did some other people, there is no evidence that the doctor did.

Comment: I didn't intend to introduce a factual error: please feel free to make the title more accurate if I screwed it up. The point of the edit was just that inbound visitors (like me, seeing this on the Hot Network Questions list three times today) have no way of knowing what the heck they're going to get when clicking on "What was written on the wall?" I'd strongly suggest that the word "Doctor" and the title of the episode appear in whatever alternate arrangement you deem necessary; that way people have some idea of the context and whether they're even going to be interested _before_ arriving.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The *Radio Times* [analyzed exactly this question](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2015-11-30/did-you-spot-this-hidden-message-in-doctor-who-heaven-sent). According to them, the writing reads:

> As you come into this world,
>   something else is also born.
>   You begin your life,
>   and it begins a journey.
>   Towards you.
>   Wherever you go.
>   Whatever path you take.
>   It will follow.
>   You will notice a second
>   shadow next to yours.
>   Your life will then be over.

It's easier to make out with a sharper image, again provided by the *Radio Times*:

[image]

Comment: Jason "Tom" Baker!

Comment: Which is, of course, just what the Doctor says in the voiceover at the start.

Comment: It may or may not be relevant to notice that the actual words written on the wall are I instead of It after 'You begin your life, and it begins a journey'

Comment: @Jason I've converted your answer to a comment as you don't have enough rep yet. Please take the [tour] to find out more.